# MVC 4 Default Parameter Value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

In MVC 4 application while defining routing I can provide a list of default parameters. What value shall I provide for optional parameter: `UrlParameter.Optional` or *empty string*?

Examples:

```c#
routes.MapRoute("simple", "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
  new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional});
```

```c#
routes.MapRoute("simple", "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
  new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = ""});
```

Is there any difference between `id = ""` and `id = UrlParameter.Optional` in above examples?

Please note that some controller actions will be using `id` (of type `string`) and some will be parameterless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is subtle and but almost unimportant

`UrlParameter.Optional` means a null will be passed to the Action Method in lieu of a value.

`id = ""` means a default value of "" (not null) will be passed to the Action Method.

In both cases, not including an id parameter in your route will NOT stop the MVC framework from finding the right method.

In the case of `UrlParameter.Optional`, you should make all relatable Action Methods take a nullable parameter

**Type matters**

You should NOT apply `id=""` to routes that use ints.

Comment: Also of importance is only the last parameter in the list can have a default value of `UrlParameter.Optional`