# What's happening here? What kind of member is "Optional"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

Can anyone tell me what is happening in below code. What is the reason behind declaring a member as the class type ??

```
    public sealed class UrlParameter
{
    // Summary:
    //     Contains the read-only value for the optional parameter.
    public static readonly UrlParameter Optional;

    // Summary:
    //     Returns an empty string. This method supports the ASP.NET MVC infrastructure
    //     and is not intended to be used directly from your code.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     An empty string.
    public override string ToString();
}
```

I saw it in the route registration method:

routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "AboutView1", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is it that you want to know? There are millions of reason for having a field of the same type as the declaring class.

Comment: Edited my question!

Comment: You already have an answer which is correct. Does that not enough? Consider going through documentation.

Comment: The MapRoute method is analysing the anonymous object behind the scenes and if the `id` is in the URL and it's of the type UrlParameter (instead of an expected value), it will check if it is the same as the Optional instance (which is a singleton) and if so, it won't get it's value, but it will consider it an optional parameter.

Comment: You can look at the implementation from here: https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/RouteCollectionExtensions.cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this may look strange to you, the `Optional` field is nothing but an implementation of the singleton design pattern ([see Static Initialization here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx)). A very special one in this case.

Because the field is marked as `static`, you'll only have one instance of the `UrlParameter` class in your application. The `readonly` modifier means that assignments to this field can only occur as part of the declaration or in a constructor in the same class ([have a look here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)). In this concrete example, `Optional` is always set to null ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14737610/mvc-4-default-parameter-value)). So it is a singleton, but merely a constant because it's defined as null.

Microsoft has probably done this so that the value of the `Optional` field may change in the future without breaking existing code ([see the difference between `const` and `static readonly`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755685/static-readonly-vs-const)) - `const` forces you to recompile all your existing code, in case of change, to make it work again, while `static readonly` doesn't.

Comment: So that's a singleton pattern implemented...!
Thanks a lot !